# How to center caption who sibling element is rotated 45 degs

Tags: html, css

I have this slider [here](http://codeandcode.co/demo/DemoTest/alefSlider/). The image is skewed to around 45deg. below is the HTML for the whole block:

```
<a href="#" class="home-slider-item gallery_item">
    <div class="home-slider-inner">
        <img src="images/b-3.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="caption-box-background">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="caption-box">
        <i class="fa fa-android "></i>
        <p>Phychological<br> Consultation</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

The transform is applied on `.home-slider-inner`

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) skew(-20deg, 0deg);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) skew(-20deg, 0deg);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) skew(-20deg, 0deg);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) skew(-20deg, 0deg);
    border-right: 5px solid orange;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    transform-origin: 0 100%;
```

So as you can see below the caption is not centered:

[image].

As of now i am applying a negative `margin-left` to the caption box to make the text look centered , but this solution does't work well on all screen sizes and needs to be added on many resolutions. So how can i center the the caption box to the image thats been skewed ?

One solution that dynamic solution i came up with is to calculate the `width` of the `skew` and then apply a negative margin to the caption box of:

```
  margin-left:  width of skew / 2;
```

Again i am not sure how to about doing this , i just think this is a possible solution. Can somebody guide me as to how can i go about centering this `caption box` without using hacky negatice `margin-left` !

P.S. since transforms make text look blurred , i had to write the caption as a separate child of the parent `a`, so if somebody answers this question , the use-case for the solution will be pretty universal.

Comment: CSS could do that on its own i believe : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zdJbxx Mind first and last element to reset a few values

Comment: If you post a working code snippet within the question (as I am sure you already know), you most likely will get a proper answer.

Comment: Also, a negativ margin is no more hacky than a negative `translate`, they both are there so one can compensate for alignments etc., and I can't see any other way here either, as the text aren't aware of the rotation since the DOM haven't changed, only visually has the image been rotated

Comment: @LGSon , thanks for your inputs as for your request, i believe the link i have added should provide a environment in which the code is isolated enough for it to be fit for another person to inspect the stated problem.

Comment: When an external link die, so does the question, and therefore a working code snippet should always be within it, or else it has little use for future users. Furthermore, it should be in your interest to simplify as much as possible to make it easy for us to test the code, and as it is now, we need to copy and paste into a test environment, create absolute paths for the images etc., ... And as you can see, you haven't got any quality answers yet, so it must be more than me who holds back. I took the time though, to inform you about this, most simply pass by with no comments

Answer (score 2):

[image]
In skew we have a case of Right-angled triangle and the skew new width is equal to "Opposite" and we've the angle and the opposite so by this equation we can get the adjacent 
Opposite = Adjacent * tan(angle); Where opposite in case of skewX is the div height and in case of skewY will be the div width

Then by adding the adjacent to the div width we can get the new width

I've created a plunkr to calculate skew new width and new height 
https://embed.plnkr.co/uBeH84h9TgBT3zaVNHBZ/

Comment: _Skew by 20 deg means the width to be increased by 20%_ ...where did you get that from? ... The length the width increases is based on the height **and** skew degree, so in this case (20deg), for 125px high it is 18.4% and for 250px it is 36.8%

Comment: @LGSon Thanks for the valuable input !

Comment: @LGSon
Thanks for your comment i've edited the answer to calculate it accurately

Answer (score 2):

The best solution would be to make the skew take place where the caption is. This way, it's horizontal alignment won't be disturbed.

I believe that this will happen aproximately here:

```
.home-slider-inner {
     transform-origin: 0 calc(50vh - 100px);
}
```

But any way, you can adapt it to your exact needs.